# What is the number of abelian groups of order 40?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the number of abelian groups of order 40? I thought the number is just $3$. More specifically, they are

$$\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_5$$
$$\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$$
$$\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_5$$

However, my answer says:[image]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your book is wrong, $\mathbb Z_{10}$ is congruent to $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_2$.

So $\mathbb Z_{10}\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ is congruent to $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: In general if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\times p_2^{\alpha_2}\times \dots \times p_s^{\alpha_s}$ then there are $\prod\limits_{i=1}^s p(\alpha_i)$ abelian groups of order $n$. Where $p$ is the partition function.

Answer (score 1):

The ones listed in the book are not distinct.

$$\Bbb Z_{40} \cong \Bbb Z_{5} \times \Bbb Z_8 $$

$$\Bbb Z_{20} \times \Bbb Z_2 \cong \Bbb Z_{10} \times \Bbb Z_4 \cong \Bbb Z_{5} \times \Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_2 $$

$$\Bbb Z_{10} \times \Bbb Z_2  \times \Bbb Z_2 \cong \Bbb Z_{5} \times \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$$